# How to edit interpolation for multiple bones in armature?

Tags: rigging, interpolation

Hello fellow blender artists,

I would really appreciate, if you could have a look at my attached animation in progress: [image]

It's a printmaking press with movable desk and felt. It took me pretty long time to figure out how to make the felt go up and cover the upper cylinder - I needed to control its folding precisely. Eventually I decided to rig the felt - and since weight painting did not work exactly how I needed (it kept breaking the felt sharply or moving some parts of the felt below the moving desk), I gave the felt 85 bones and attached them by vertex groups. Now I was able to animate the felt just how I wanted.

***But there I made a mistake.*** It was too late when I realised, that the easing-in and -out affected every single move with bones during keyframes. Now the problem is that I kept moving each bone really slightly to achieve smooth result and so in Graph editor I have no clue, how to edit the miniature bezier curves to get rid of the easing.
Additionally, when I tried to convert bone interpolation to linear (as I learned by desperate searching for a solution), I felt like this edited bone movement deformed the felt animation.

Please fellow Blender artists, is there a way to change interpolation for a whole animation - or for every animation in selected frame? Or how would you solve this problem? I will appretiate every suggestion, just so I won't make the same mistake ever again.

Thank you in advance!

Wrawraw

Comment: Select All > Key > Interpolation Mode > Linear (in the graph editor) doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will play around with it. But the animation still doesn't go smoothly. This is how it looks now: http://sendvid.com/m8jr76x6